# Using functions to compare the rates of shipping for books in Python

Tags: python, function, rate

I am supposed to grade this assignment for a professor in an introductory computer science class, but I think I am either misinterpreting the assignment or it is kind of a poorly designed problem. Here are the three parts:

1. Suppose that the cover price of a book is 24.95 dollars, however bookstores get a 40% discount. Shipping costs 3 dollars for the first copy and 75 cents for each additional copy. Write a function *wholesale(n)* that returns the total wholesale cost for an order of n books.
2. Write a second wholesale function for a different book that costs 22.95 dollars, has the same discount, but that ships for 3 dollars for the first copy and 85 cents for each additional copy. Call this function wholesale2.
3. Functions are actually objects themselves, and they have a type. As a result you can pass functions to other functions. Write a function *check_cost(p, p2, n)* that takes functions *p* and *p2* and an integer *n*, and returns a Boolean value True if p(n) > p2(n); and False otherwise. Apply it to your wholesale functions by calling: *check_cost(wholesale, wholesale2, n)* and use different values for n until you find where the order of the costs changes.

In theory this is a pretty basic concept, however the two functions that I have written crossover at zero (and in this context we should only need to consider positive integers), and I feel like this defeats the point of the assignment especially in the context, where one should be cheaper for some number of books, but if you buy in bulk ultimately the other should be cheaper - at least that is what I was expecting.

Here is my chunk of code:

```
def wholesale(n):
    book_cost = 0.6 * 24.95 * n # the price of the book with a forty percent discount times the number of books
    shipping_cost = 3 + .75*(n-1) # this way shipping is exactly $3 for one book
    total_cost = book_cost + shipping_cost
    return total_cost

def wholesale2(n):
    book_cost = 0.6 * 22.95 * n # the price of the book with a forty percent discount times the number of books
    shipping_cost = 3 + .85*(n-1) # this way shipping is exactly $3 for one book
    total_cost = book_cost + shipping_cost
    return total_cost

def check_cost(p, p2, n):
    if (p > p2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

for n in range(-5, 100):
    print(check_cost(wholesale(n), wholesale2(n), n))
```

The final statement is just what I was using to determine the crossover, after I realized that it is not at a positive integer point, which again I feel defeats the point of the problem. Have I misinterpreted the question and incorrectly written the two functions? Or is it a poorly designed problem? Additionally, the *check_cost* function seems poorly designed by the nature he wants, as I feel as if there is no reason to pass the parameter *n* if we just need to compare the values of the two functions at *n*.

Please let me know if I am simply overlooking something. I plan to talk to the professor who wrote this assignment, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious first.

Comment: `book_cost = 0.4 * 24.95 * n` The discount is 40%, so the cost should be 60% of 24.95, not 40%.

Comment: @JohnGordon Good catch, thank you. I will revise that

Comment: @rabinnh I agree this may not be the most efficient program, however it is how the teacher requires that it is written, per the instructions provided. It is for an intro programming class so that students can learn about writing function definitions and passing functions as parameters in another function.

Comment: How can minus n books be ordered? And n=0 will just result in the shipping ($3  - 0.75 or - 0.8) according to your algorithm which again is not sensible (paying to deliver nothing!).

Comment: @user19077881 regardless of the base case of zero books, which I know could be dealt with with an if statement, the question I am asking remains

Comment: I think you are missing the point for the check_cost function. The intention seems to be to pass it just the function names and n value and call the two wholesale functions as p(n) and p2(n) inside check_cost. This illustrates that functions in Python can be used in this way which is an important point. Surely a range from 1 should be used.

Comment: @DylanWarcholik The problem is poorly designed, because a cursory glance at the values should be enough to determine that a crossover won't ever occur. A computer program isn't needed for that - just a basic grasp of arithmetic. I strongly suspect that either there's a typo in the problem statement, or the author just assumed a crossover would occur without actually checking beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You say that

> the two functions that I have written crossover at zero

and my understanding is that you contemplate on the case when n is 0. If so, then your functions as they are written are correctly assessing that `book_cost` is 0, but incorrectly assessing that `shipping_cost` is 3. It is not 3, because we only have a shipping cost starting from the first book. Therefore, in your functions it makes sense to check whether `n <= 0` and if so, return 0.

Then you say:

> The final statement is just what I was using to determine the crossover, after I realized that it is not at a positive integer point, which again I feel defeats the point of the problem. Have I misinterpreted the question and incorrectly written the two functions? Or is it a poorly designed problem?

I think it is deliberate in order to make you think. Because the first is being greater than the second at n = 1 and at each increment of n the difference increases.

So you are supposed to search for the crossover for positive n until you realize that it will not happen (unless you get into a number overflow for an n high-enough). Therefore you either conclude that there is no crossover, or that the crossover is below, depending on what you define as the domain of n. Again, for non-positives your function should return sensible values.

The task does not say anything about the cases when n <= 0, it only speaks about the first book and subsequent books, so it is up to you to handle these edge cases.

Finally, you say:

> Additionally, the check_cost function seems poorly designed by the nature he wants, as I feel as if there is no reason to pass the parameter n if we just need to compare the values of the two functions at n.

Here you clearly misunderstood the point. The point was to pass the functions to `check_cost` and `n`, but you pass the return value of these functions and `n` instead. The idea is that if you implement `wholesale3`, `wholesale4`, etc., then you should be able to pass them to `check_cost`.

The idea is to use `wholesale` and `wholesale2` as [callbacks](https://www.askpython.com/python/built-in-methods/callback-functions-in-python), that is, functions that are passed (and not their return values) to `check_cost` and then those functions are called inside `check_cost` and their results are compared. This will allow `check_cost` to compare the result of any two functions for `n`, including, but not limited to your two wholesale functions.

Comment: Thank you for your response about using wholesale as callbacks and not passing the return values, I now see my error with that part of the program. Additionally, I agree that the edge cases should be considered, this was just a lazy approach to determine where the values cross over since I was expecting it to be at a positive integer point. You may be right that the student is supposed to conclude that the ey never cross over, it was just an unexpected problem, and I feel like the wording of the questions had suggested that there would be a crossover point. Regardless, thanks for your input :)

Comment: @DylanWarcholik happy to help. We cannot know for sure what the intention of your teacher was, but in reality you will meet such cases when you expect something and you get something completely different. If I were you, I would not ask the teacher about this, but write my findings into a paper or as comments to the code so the teacher will see what your thinking was. If this answer helped you, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `check_cost` is to compare the outputs of two functions (`p` and `p2`) when passed the same argument `n`. In the way you've implemented `check_cost`, you're not actually calling the funcions `p` and `p2` inside `check_cost`. Instead, you're comparing the function objects themselves, which is not the intended behavior:

```py
def check_cost(p, p2, n):
    return p(n) > p2(n)
```

And then, when you loop through the values of `n` to find the crossover point, you're correctly passing the functions `wholesale` and `wholesale2` to `check_cost`, but the loop starts from -5, which doesn't make sense with the context of the problem that deals with positive integers representing the number of books. What it should be like is:

```py
for n in range(1, 100):
    print(n, check_cost(wholesale, wholesale2, n))
```

The problem itself is an effective way to practice with functions and arithmetic in Python. Your confusion stemmed from the implementation of `check_cost` and the misuse of the functions within it.

Stack's here to answer questions, but asking this in stack is not a great way of learning how to do it yourself I guess.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the input about passing a method as a parameter, that certainly did help my understanding of that part of the problem. The cases I used going from -5 to 100 was simply to demonstrate that only for values less than zero does wholesale2 have a larger cost than wholesale, but in the context of the problem I expected that to be at the point of a positive integer, not a value below zero. It is possible that it is with the intention of having the student determine that wholesale is always more expensive than wholesale2, but it was not what I expected or how I would have designed it.